# Hadoop and Eclipse - Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4

Tags: 14.04, java, eclipse, hadoop

I'm working on Ubuntu and using Eclipse to work with Hadoop. After setting the Run configuration, a message says `Incomplete HDFS URI, no host`

**UPDATE:** found the solution! but after running the program, the message says `Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4`

**Solution:** It seems I added a jar file used for Hadoop 1 version. Removed it and placed a new version :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for your core-site.xml.
Mine looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost/</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

when i am running the code from my Eclipse IDE.

Also please make sure that /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*.jar(I have Cloudera Hadoop distribution) is in your Build path.